# Values of a form's fields to an Ajax call using Dojo

Tags: ajax, json, dojo

I have a form like this (from a widget template):

```
   '<div>' +
    '  <form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="form" method="POST"> ' +
    '    <label for="${id}_workspace">Workspace name</label>  ' +
    '    <input name="workspace" id="${id}_workspace" data-dojo-attach-point="workspace" data-dojo-type="app.ValidationWorkspace" />' +
    '    <label for="${id}_password1">Password</label>  ' +
    '    <input name="password[0]" id="${id}_password1" data-dojo-attach-point="password1" data-dojo-type="app.ValidationPassword" />' +
    '    <label for="${id}_password1">Confirm password</label>  ' +
    '    <input name="password[1]" id="${id}_password2" data-dojo-attach-point="password2" data-dojo-type="app.ValidationPassword" />' +
    '    <input type="submit" data-dojo-attach-point="button" data-dojo-type="app.BusyButton" label="Create!" />' +
    '  </form>' +
    '</div>',
```

In the code, I wrote:

```
        data = {};
        data.workspace = that.workspace.get('value');
        data.password = [];
        data.password[0] = that.password1.get('value');
        data.password[1] = that.password2.get('value');

        // Store the data 
        g.stores.workspacesAnon.put(data).then(
          function(res){
            console.log("Jsonrest put(data) returned OK: " + json.toJson(res) );
            that.button.cancel();
          }
        );
```

Two actual questions:

1. If I use that.form.value.email instead of  that.password1.get('value'), sometimes outdated values are submitted to the form (!). For example, if I type something in the password2 field and hit enter straight away, the actual submission happens for the expected in Dojo? How come does it happen?
2. Is there a better way to get the form's values, so that 'password[0]' and 'password[1]' become an array automatically etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every widget under dijit.form makes sure that the one form element with the correct name is updated with its value, even if the values are something like a filtering select click or a date in a calendar.

With that said, we know that a common form.submit() will work as expected.

However while doing the submission as an AJAX request, we need to loop the form-elements for their values and make it a json key value object.

You have it easy, dojo.xhrPost does this internally if called like this:

```
dojo.xhrPost ( {
   url: 'submiturl.sapi',
   form: dojo.byId('myFormDomId')
} )
```

For higher level of control you can use either `dojo.formToJson` or `dijit.form.Form.getValues` - e.g. these two variants

```
var values = dojo.formToJson(dojo.byId('myFormDomId'));
// OR
var values = dijit.byId('myFormDijitId').getValues();
// mod or mixin your custom values, examplewise
values = dojo.mixin(values, {   anotherVariable: 'sentAsPostParam'   });

dojo.xhrPost ( {
    url: 'submitUrl.sapi',
    content : values
} );
```

In regards to your first question 1)
If a validator is attached to the widget email - and the validation renders in-valid, the input element is not set accordingly. Setting value is done once there's either 1 - keyup event or 2 - onblur event. To ensure that correct values are sent, use `dijit.form.Form.validate` (seeing as you allready have extended your form dojoType) like this

```
var formWidget = dijit.byId('myFormDijitId');
if(formWidget.validate()) {  // loops all form widgets and 'sums' up their validators
   dojo.xhrPost( { url: 'submiturl.sapi', content: formWidget.getValues() } );
}
```

EDIT:

specifically for creating a nested array within the item, OP needs for the JsonRest store - it is nescessary to call the input elements by the excact same name, e.g.

```
<input name="password" 
                        id="${id}_password1" data-dojo-attach-point="password1" data-dojo-type="app.ValidationPassword" />
<input name="password" 
                        id="${id}_password2" data-dojo-attach-point="password2" data-dojo-type="app.ValidationPassword" />
```

Also, make use of dojo.formToJson on the native form element, like so (do it **after validation** to assert values being set):

```
    g.stores.workspacesAnon.put(
       dojo.formToJson(widgetReference.form.domNode)
    ).then( ... );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But... `formWidget.getValues()` doesn't create an object where `password[0]' and 'password[1]` are merged into a nice array called `password` with two elements! Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: (Please keep in mind that I am saving a store: `workspacesAnon.put(data)` so `data` needs to be a "normal" array!)

Comment: ah i missed the fact, that youre actually not calling the XHR yourself, yea. In that case, go with NO [0-1-2] in your `input name=pass` and use dojo.formToJson (see http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/pnMz6/)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `dojo.xhrPost()` specifying your form, see [this link](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrPost.html) and take a look at example 1 where it sends the dojo.byId("myform") . I'm guessing you can call it this way and not worry about how to pass those parameters to the server. That should fix the issue of sending outdated parameters.

If you need anything comment on this.

Luck,